# how can I access controller by URL?

Tags: angularjs

in angular, using routeProvider, we can create dynamical template by this way:

```
$routeProvider.when('/dev/:parent/:name', {

            templateUrl: function(p) {
                console.log('app.config.js: DEV_MODE TEMPLATE');
                return 'Views/Layouts/' + p.parent + '/' + p.name + 'Layout.html'
            },
            controller: function($routeParams) {
                console.log('app.config.js: DEV_MODE CONTROLLER');
                return $routeParams.name + 'Controller';
            },
        });
```

I want to know if I can control the controller by URL, such as

```
  return 'Controllers/' + p.parent + '/' + p.name + 'Ctrl.js'
```

Comment: You can take advantage of the `resolve` property part of the route options to fetch the controller JS (as a promise) and then use the [`register`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider) function to register the fetched controller function. Good example here: https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can take advantage of the resolve property part of the route options to fetch the controller JS (as a promise) and then use the register function to register the fetched controller function.